# Was Spock ever successful at reunifying the Vulcan and Romulan peoples?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, spock

After the two part TNG episode "Reunification" was Spock able to unify the two peoples?

Comment: Well, a crazy Romulan went back in time and destroyed Vulcan as part of a personal vendetta against Spock, creating an alternate timeline in the process, so I’m gonna speculate that no, he didn’t quite manage it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the main canon, the answer is a very firm no. The last word on the subject seems to be the flash-forward in the (canon) comic [Countdown #01](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Countdown) in which we see that **shortly before Romulus' destruction**, Vulcan and Romulus had normalised ambassadorial relations and begun to allow inward immigration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The fact that he was making progress towards Reunification just makes the destruction of Romulus that much sadder for Spock. In every way possible, he failed to save the Romulans.

Comment: @Omegacron - Worse than that, it was arguably his actions that doomed Romulus in the main continuity and Vulcan in the reboot continuity

Comment: Wait, are comics canon even though books aren't? This is even nutsier than DarthMickey rules!

Comment: @DVK - The new "Countdown" and "Ongoing" comics are considered to be fully canon. The old TNG comics are considered to be non-canon. None of the books are considered to be canon, nor have they ever been. As per usual, the novelisations sit inside their own wacky little grey area.